# Where is start symbol in cat executable?

Tags: linux, assembly

In my Ubuntu 18.04, when I disassemble `/bin/cat` or the one in coreutils using IDA Pro there exists "`start`" symbol, usually found with name "`_start`" in other programs such as `gimp`.

However, when I use `nm` to find the symbols even with `-D` switch, I am not able to find any `start` symbol. Why is that?

My task is to find a symbol pointing to the entry point of a given program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point of a binary is found using a point in its header; in [ELF binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) as used on Linux, this is the 32- or 64-bit value at offset 0x18.

You can see this by running `objdump -f` on the binary.

`nm` will only show an actual symbol for this, assuming it’s really generated by the compiler, if the debugging symbols for the binary are available, either directly in the binary (if it isn’t stripped), or as detached symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did know the address of the entry point in the elf file, however I am more interested to find symbol pointing to it as I want to have the entry point address during run-time (Due to ASLR, address of the entrypoint in elf file is not the address during execution). Anyway, is there any flag I can pass during compilation to not stripping the symbols if that is the cause?

Comment: You can avoid passing `-s` to the compiler, or avoid running `strip`. With an Ubuntu package you can also install the detached debugging symbols package. But I get the impression there might not even be a symbol for the entry point...